# Oracle 12c: ORA-06575 Package or function name_of_func is in an invalid state

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to create a function that takes an input(character data) and replaces a set of specific characters.
The function I have created so far is the following

```
CREATE FUNCTION name_of_func(input VARCHAR(4000)
  RETURN VARCHAR(4000) IS
  BEGIN
    return replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(input, '\', '\\'), CHR(10), '\n'), CHR(13) || CHR(10), '\n'), CHR(13), '\n'),'"', '\"');
  END name_of_func;
```

How can I get this function to be compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the size of parameters in the function definition:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name_of_func(input VARCHAR)
  2    RETURN VARCHAR IS
  3    BEGIN
  4      return replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(input, '\', '\\'), CHR(10), '\n'), CHR(13) || CHR(10), '\n'), CHR(13), '\n'),'"', '\"');
  5    END name_of_func;
  6  /

Function created.

SQL> select name_of_func('dfghjk') from dual;

NAME_OF_FUNC('DFGHJK')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dfghjk

SQL>
```

Comment: This compiles and works; just showing. Are you sure you run the same code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify variable sizes in the function declaration, also, you need to swap the order of the replacements so that `\r\n` is replaced before `\n` or `\r` are handled individually.

```
CREATE FUNCTION name_of_func(
  input VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  return replace(
           replace(
             replace(
               replace(
                 replace( input, '\', '\\'),
                 CHR(13)||CHR(10),
                 '\n'
               ),
               CHR(10),
               '\n'
             ),
             CHR(13),
             '\n'
           ),
           '"',
           '\"'
         );
END name_of_func;
```